# When a 7 is rolled, are the cards discarded randomly?

Tags: catan

When a 7 is rolled, and a person has more than 7 cards, do the cards get discarded randomly or does the card holder get to pick which one(s) to discard?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, the card holder chooses.

From the [rules](http://www.catan.com/service/game-rules), page 11 (emphasis is mine):

> Each player counts his Resource Cards. Any player with more than 7 Resource Cards (i.e., 8 or more), must **choose** and discard half of them.